# AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding Unsafe Encryption Mode error

Tags: android, encryption, google-play-console, caesar-cipher, android-security

I got an warning from google to Change encryption mode from "AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding" to "AES/GCM/NoPadding".
After changing I need to be compatible with the old data which is encrypted with "AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding".
Can you please help with a goof solution to do this.
Right now I am using simple try catch.

```
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
     cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
    byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encryptedString);
```

Comment: Data encrypted with ECB cannot be decrypted with GCM, i.e. the data must be migrated (with corresponding effort), i.e. decrypted with ECB and re-encrypted with GCM. Note that GCM uses a tag and (random) nonce, which must be taken into account in the migration strategy.

Comment: ECB mode is insecure. You should use a more secure mode, such as CBC or CTR. To see why it is insecure, google "ECB penguin".

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to do the migration of the data. By what I mean decrypting the data using the old algorithm(which you are doing in your code snippet) and then encrypting it again but using the new algorithm(which is the `AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding` in your case).

In order to keep track of whether the user's data was already migrated you can use a simple flag saved in e.g `SharedPreferences` to mark data as migrated after a successful operation.

If you want to read a comprehensive guide on GCM encryption on Android please check this [article](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/doing-aes-gcm-in-android-adventures-in-the-field-72617401269d). It would be helpful as like [@Topaco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9014097/topaco) mentioned in comment GCM is more difficult to use due to some additional stuff being used than just simple `AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding` (which is [insecure](https://www.ubiqsecurity.com/ecb-vs-cbc-block-cipher-mode-differences/) by the way).